# sql - Companies which serve specific state

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table (MySQL InnoDB) of companies with respective address. A company serve clients of it city. 
With that, I included a column to set others regions (states) the company can serve, and other column to set if the company serve all the country:

```
id  State   City            Street      Name            OtherRegions    serveCountry
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   CA      Los Angeles     Street      Microsoft       NULL            NULL
2   NY      New York        Street2     Mercur chip     CA              NULL
3   NY      Buffalo         street3     apple inc       NULL            1
4   TX      Houston         street4     Climp corp      CA;NY           NULL
5   CA      San Francisco   street5     Motorola        NULL            NULL
6   TX      San Antonio     street6     HP Inc.         NULL            NULL
7   CA      San Francisco   street7     sony            NULL            NULL
```

My question is: How can I get the cities of the specific state with the count of companies which serve the respective city?

Expected results:

**CA state**

```
City            Number of Companies serve
-----------------------------------------------------------
Los Angeles     4 (Microsoft, Mercur, Apple, Climp)
San Francisco   4 (Mercur, Apple, Climp, Motorola, Sony)
```

**NY State**

```
City            Number of Companies serve
-----------------------------------------------------------
New York        3 (Mercur, Apple, Climp)
Buffalo         2 (Apple, Climp)
```

Can I do it in the same query or I have to do that in multiple queries (PHP)?

Let's assume don't have regions/sub-regions exceptions.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is not good relational design. OtherRegions should be a child table with a record for each region the company serves.

Comment: Why does Mercur belong in both SF and LA?

Comment: @NevilleK, because Mercur serve the state of CA...

Comment: @VikingBlooded a new table with columns: companyID and regions?

Comment: @brnmonteiro  Yes. Anytime you can answer "yes" to the question: can this object have more than one value for this field at the same time?, then you should populate that data in a child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by to get a list of the cities and number_of_companies serve but this wont give the companies in ().

```
Select city, count(*) as 'Number of companies serve'
from some_table
group by state
```

Your table assumes that companies all serve a city within the state they are in.
It also is wont be possible to list all the companies that serve a city since that info isn't in your table, unless you assume a company serves all the cities in its OtherRegions?

Comment: Yes, if a company serve other state, = serve all the cities of this state

Comment: In that case I would suggest, as others have mentioned, creating another table with the ID and regions served. As it stands there is nothing that says CA includes San Fran and LA or that NY includes NY and Buffalo, so these cant be included in the count.